# Module.filter not work in nested view

Tags: angularjs, uiview, filter, module

I have this code:

```
Var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'credit-cards']);

myApp.filter('yesNo', function () {
  return function (boolean) {
    return boolean ? 'Yes' : 'No';
  }


});



myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state("home", {
  redirectTo: 'home.index',
  url: "/home",
  templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
  controller:'profileCtrl',
  access: {restricted: true}
})

.state("home.index",{
  url: "/inicio",
  templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
  controller:'schedulerController',
  access: {restricted: true}

})

.state("home.canchas",{
  url: "/canchas",
  templateUrl: 'templates/canchas.html',
  access: {restricted: true}

})

.state("home.usuarios",{
  url: "/usuarios",
  templateUrl: 'templates/usuarios.html',
  controller:'usuarioController',
  access: {restricted: true}
})

.state("home.torneos",{
  url: "/torneos",
  templateUrl: 'templates/torneos.html',
  access: {restricted: true}
})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home/inicio");
});
```

This is the template:

```
 <Div class="container">
      <form name="ccForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cardNumber" cc-    number cc-eager-type name="ccNumber" ng-model="card.number">
        </div>
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Valid</th>
            <th>Eager Type</th>
            <th>Type</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{ccForm.ccNumber.$valid | yesNo}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ccForm.ccNumber.$ccEagerType || 'Unknown'}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ccForm.ccNumber.$ccType || 'Unknown'}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And then I have the routes and states.
My problem is, if I use the filter in the principal index.html, the filter works ok, but when I put the html code in other nested view, the code does not work!

Thank in advance!

Comment: Where is the nested view?

Comment: home.torneos is the nested view!